# Removing sandbox accounts from tvOS 13

Tags: in-app-purchase, tvos, apple-tv, tvos13

I have been developing a tvOS app that uses in-app purchasing. As part of the development process, the app must be tested using iTunes sandbox user accounts. When beginning the in-app purchase using a local build, the user is prompted for the account credentials to one of these sandbox accounts.

The problem arises with tvOS 13, which does not appear to let you log out from or remove a sandbox account from the device once entered. While this might be okay for purchasing a single time, going through the purchase process again requires a new sandbox account, since otherwise, the purchase would be treated as a renewal rather than a new purchase.

Has anyone figured out a way to log out of a sandbox account with an Apple TV running tvOS 13? The only workaround I have found is to perform a reset on the device and go through the setup process again costing a great deal of time.

Comment: Does deleting the sandbox user in App Store Connect work?

Comment: This is still not fixed in tvOS 13.2 beta 4.

Comment: @enc_life Good idea, but it didn't work. The account is still showing on the Apple TV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tvOS 13.4 (17L256) contains an update that allows you to sign out of the Sandbox account.

`Settings` > `Users and Accounts` > Scroll down to `Sandbox Account` > click on the email address > click `Delete` in the confirmation dialog > you're signed out

[image: Screen shot of the Users and Accounts screen with focus on Sandbox Account]

[image: Screen shot of the Remove Sandbox Account confirmation dialog]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to log out on 13 OS . If you want to make a new purchase, just make sure you are logged out from AppleID (not sandbox). then if you make a new purchase within the app it will pop up to enter sandbox and will automatically replace old Sandbox with the new one

Comment: I had a few folks try this solution and it did not work. Thanks anyway.